# VScode doesn't allow to make a fully qualified constructor call in c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

The problem with this code is that vscode shows an error message that a fully qualified constructor call is not allowed.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    class Bank{
    private:
        double balance;
    public:
        void deposit(double money){
            balance = balance + money;
            cout << balance;
        };
        void withdraw(double money){
            balance = balance - money;
            cout << balance;
        }
    };
    Bank::Bank(){

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to define the constructor or call it? If the former you need to declare it first and you'll need to move everything outside of your `main` function too

Comment: VS Code does not prevent you from doing anything. The C++ compiler does. VS Code is a code editor.

Comment: Putting classes into a function is allowed (with some restrictions), but it is not what you usually want to do.

Comment: @JeJo First, there is no typo in the question. Second, your suggestion that change `Bank::Bank` to `Bank` won't work. Third, just saying that there is a typo(even when there isn't) isn't enough. You should explain why the code gives error also.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you haven't explicitly declared the default constructor inside the class so that the compiler will **automatically synthesize** the default ctor for you but then *we're not allowed to define the implicitly declared default ctor outside the class*. Also, note that we can't provide a function or member function definition inside another function(like `main`). That is `Bank::Bank(){}` cannot be put inside `main`.

Thus to solve this error you can move the whole class outside the `main` function and add a declaration for the default constructor inside the class and then define it outside the class as shown below:

```
class Bank{
    private:
        double balance;
    public:
        void deposit(double money){
            balance = balance + money;
            cout << balance;
        };
        void withdraw(double money){
            balance = balance - money;
            cout << balance;
        }
        Bank();   //added this declaration
};
Bank::Bank(){ //now this works 

}
int main(){
    
}
```